# How to slice a string in multiple parts using a C macro?

Tags: c, macros

I want to fill a multidimensional array using a macro so that the people using it think that they are using a function and passing only one string. The macro will use this string and at compile time convert it so that it would appear as a multidimensional array, like this:

```
make_array ("string1,{string2,{string3,{...,{stringN");
```

So the macro will replace this function to a multidimensional array and cut that string wherever it encounters`,{`. The code above will turn in something like this:

```
make_array = { "string1", "string2", "string3", ..., "stringN"};
```

I'm using GCC; how can I accomplish this?

Update: I thought I could exclude the quotes of the string using a macro, so I would have a string without a text and I could edit the string in macro but GCC does not accept the declaration of a macro to replace double quotes (like shown below).

```
#define macro_array ( "text") text
```

So the text will appear without double quotes and I could find the `,{` mark and cut it and use then stringify to turn the string back.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a moderate approximation to what you are after with C99 and variable arguments in macros:

#### Source

```
#define make_array(name, dim1, dim2, ...) \
            static char name[dim1][dim2] = { __VA_ARGS__ }

make_array(mine, 2, 2, "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl");
```

#### Output

```
$: gcc -E xx.c
# 1 "xx.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "xx.c"

static char mine[2][2] = { "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" };
$
```

However, you cannot readily split a string in the preprocessor as requested - it is simply the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do string processing with macros.

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but this is probably best achieved with a function.

Comment: I want to save resources doing it in compile time

Comment: @drigo: You can't.  Maybe you should modify your question to explain what you're trying to *achieve* with all this.  This might help you get better answers.

Comment: C++ is much better than C at saving resource by doing things at compile time.

Comment: first I only want to put the stuff right to save a lot of time in processing and checking char per char. Second I don't want to change my taste about programming language only to do that thing

Comment: I am saying, macros are the wrong tool for this job.  This is not the language for that kind of optimization.  You need a different tool (maybe a new build step to call 'sed' on your data to replace ',{' with '","') or a different approach (such as runtime string tokenization).

Comment: Too much time and effort put into something that brings absolutely NO real value or benefit. This looks more like a pessimisation. But if OP wants to learn from this task, I won't bring more obstacles than the task itself.

Answer (score 3):

Forget it. I see way too many questions along the lines of "How can I make my code look like this?" when the question for achieving good code should be "How can I make my code **work** like this?" What is the goal you're trying to achieve?

If you want to import external data that was formatted in the weird notation you specified, does the data vary at runtime or is it constant? In the former case you'll need a parser in your program and a good deal of dynamic allocation. In the latter case, you need to write a program that runs before compiling the main program which parses and converts the data into C. But if there's no legitimate reason for the data to be in this weird format to begin with, you should simply write it in C from the start rather than trying to force C to look like something else.

Comment: The preprocessor cannot do what you asked for. You can write your own preprocessor, but I still think what you're trying to achieve is of dubious value.

Comment: of course archieve this is a GREAT challenge and write my own preprocessor is a big not so great as challenge

Comment: Some people try to invent perpetual motion machines, and others try to make the C preprocessor split strings for them. Oh well.

Comment: And some people try to stop these ones, always is well

Answer (score 1):

1. Get rid of the quotes and use a variadic macro
2. Write a function to split the string and call it from the macro
3. Don't use macros for this, just make a static inline function.  It is just as fast.

Answer (score 0):

As Oli has already said, this kind of string processing is impossible with macros. Concatenation and replacement of other strings is about as much as you can do with macros.

I think the answer here is a question- why does the input string have to be of that format? Writing your required result does not require any more effort than it is to write your input, so why would you want to go through the pain of processing it?